# Is it possible to draw gridlines ABOVE a filled linechart?

Tags: mpandroidchart

In all the examples I have found when a linechart is filled (gradient or solid color) , this filling covers the gridlines and they dissapear. Is it possible to draw the gridlines over them?

I have tried to include .setDrawGridLines(true);, but nothing changes[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false)` on the relevant chart axis to have it draw the grid lines in front of the data. For example:

```java
YAxis yAx = chart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
yAx.setDrawGridLines(true);
yAx.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false);

XAxis xAx = chart.getXAxis();
xAx.setDrawGridLines(true);
xAx.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false);
```

Comment: Great!. As simple as that. I have spent hours looking for the solution and didn't notice about this method. Thanks a lot, Tyler.